# Installing "py3exiv2" module on windows

Tags: python-3.x, pip

## `pip install py3exiv2`

Whenever i try to install "*py3exiv2"* module, some error messages appear :

```
Collecting py3exiv2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/56/52cc6757f24d828e9db35e8f24091ac1529471dd8c16b532925f4d89f0ca/py3exiv2-0.3.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: py3exiv2
  Running setup.py install for py3exiv2 ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\nagasia.desktop-4proa3l\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NAGASI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sgx1rihl\\py3exiv2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NAGASI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-isqztm52\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    FIND: modificador no v lido
    FIND: modificador no v lido
    FIND: modificador no v lido
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    copying src\pyexiv2\exif.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    copying src\pyexiv2\iptc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    copying src\pyexiv2\metadata.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    copying src\pyexiv2\preview.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    copying src\pyexiv2\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    copying src\pyexiv2\xmp.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    copying src\pyexiv2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyexiv2
    running build_ext
    building 'libexiv2python' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\nagasia.desktop-4proa3l\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\nagasia.desktop-4proa3l\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/exiv2wrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src/exiv2wrapper.obj -g
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-g'
    exiv2wrapper.cpp
    c:\users\nagasia.desktop-4proa3l\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-sgx1rihl\py3exiv2\src\exiv2wrapper.hpp(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'exiv2/image.hpp': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\nagasia.desktop-4proa3l\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NAGASI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sgx1rihl\\py3exiv2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NAGASI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-isqztm52\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NAGASI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sgx1rihl\py3exiv2\
```

Is there anything that I could do such that it would install normaly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make use of the many formatting possibilities in StackOverflow. Presenting a nicely readable question increases the possibility of getting an answer greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compile code using VisualC++, but the code is configured for a Linux environment and needs the Gnu compiler.

As it requires a lot of knowledge to adapt and reconfigure the code, I suggest you use a ready-to-run module for Windows 10, e. g. *piexif*.